# Anaconda Prompt Corrupts after Installation

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow

I just installed **Tensorflow-gpu** after creating a separate **environment** following the instructions from [here](https://github.com/antoniosehk/keras-tensorflow-windows-installation). However post installation when I close the Prompt window and open a **new terminal** the following error pops up. I have set the Anaconda/Scripts and Anaconda path to the Environment Variable too still this doesn't seem to get resolved. Any solution is appreciated.

> usage: conda [-h]
>                {keygen,sign,unsign,verify,unpack,install,install-
>       scripts,convert,version,help}
>                ...
>       conda: error: invalid choice: '..checkenv' (choose from 'keygen', 'sign', 
>       'unsign', 'verify', 'unpack', 'install', 'install-scripts', 'convert', 
>       'version', 'help')

```
C:\Users\sashw>activate keras
'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Try to start a new terminal.

Comment: open cmd.exe and do `dir /S activate*` wait and see where activate then is located, cd to that directory and see if you can then run it, if you can, then add that path, you  CD'd to as the path in the environment.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
The only way to fix the issue that I found was to re-install Conda from scratch and replace the tensorflow installation by this command (removed '--ignore-installed --upgrade'):

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you are not inheriting the previous system wide path when you define a new "PATH" environment variable. Your changes to the path seem to be wiping out conda from the path. Make sure any PATH environment variable you define in the variable editor has %PATH% in it (the instructions linked above do not seem to elucidate that detail). I.e. if you echo %PATH% on a new shell after you set your environment, it should have not just the thing you added it. It should also have conda (and probably other stuff) in it.