# Anaconda commands stopped working

Tags: python, anaconda

I was trying to install tensorflow with gpu in a conda environment and it didn't work because apparently, tf only has support for until V8 of CUDA.
I'm working in a windows 10 computer.

After that i can't activate or run any command from anaconda. Examples:

```
C:\Users\User>activate keras
usage: conda [-h]
             {keygen,sign,unsign,verify,unpack,install,install-scripts,convert,version,help}
             ...
conda: error: invalid choice: 'activate' (choose from 'keygen', 'sign', 'unsign', 'verify', 'unpack', 'install', 'install-scripts', 'convert', 'version', 'help')

C:\Users\User>conda list
usage: conda [-h]
             {keygen,sign,unsign,verify,unpack,install,install-scripts,convert,version,help}
             ...
conda: error: invalid choice: 'list' (choose from 'keygen', 'sign', 'unsign', 'verify', 'unpack', 'install', 'install-scripts', 'convert', 'version', 'help')
```

I can't find anything helpful online and although I could reinstall anaconda i would prefer not to. Any solutions?

Comment: You may be trying to use virtual environments. Check out this documentation. https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: `conda activate keras` would not work either way.  you just need `activate keras` (no leading `conda`).

Comment: This was a sample case. The problem happens too with activate keras obviously. I will edit. Thanks

Comment: @JMaurer I'm trying to use my virtual envs. I can't activate neither or actually call any command in anaconda.

Comment: This appears to be an error with the tensorflow-gpu installation instructions. I have been searching this all day. There are several recent threads in multiple places citing this problem. Will add solution if it exists.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356732/anaconda-prompt-corrupts-after-installation